# Wordpress call wp_insert_post without triggering save_post

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible ? I am trying to populate WP database with some legacy posts but dont want to trigger the current work flow we have. Just want to create them silently. Or is my only option is to directly write to database ?

Answer (score 0):

save_post is an action built into the function. Is your workflow based on the post status? Or actually triggered whenever save_post is? If it's based on the post status being set to publish, then you can set the post status to draft or pending.

Comment: I have a bunch of actions on save_post. I think I am going to call remove_all_actions('save_post'), create my post and then restore the actions. Hopefully that should work I guess

Comment: Yeah, that should. Without understanding the need to hook to save_post for the workflow, I usually create a custom post status for each step and then trigger from that.